# Matching the lines with specific start and end character patterns using regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to get the values dba, dba1, dba2 from a file which I read in memory and stored in data variable.

```
/host/sec/sc1/db_usr/user = dba
/host/sec/sc1/db_usr1/user = dba1
/host/sec/sc1/db_usr2/user = dba2
```

I am trying the following regex:

```
data.split("\n").grep(/\/host\/sec\/S\/user/).map{ |l| l.split.last }
```

But it's returning `nil` value.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
> str = "/host/sec/sc1/db_usr/user = dba
* /host/sec/sc1/db_usr1/user = dba1
* /host/sec/sc1/db_usr2/user = dba2"
=> "/host/sec/sc1/db_usr/user = dba\n/host/sec/sc1/db_usr1/user = dba1\n/host/sec/sc1/db_usr2/user = dba2"

> str.scan(%r!/user = (.*)?(?:\n|\z)!).flatten
=> ["dba", "dba1", "dba2"]
```

There is probably a better way that wouldn't involve `flatten` but the above works.

Here's another option:

```
> str.split("\n").map {|e| e.split(" = ").last}
=> ["dba", "dba1", "dba2"]
```